# A Couple of Subset Questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give examples of sets A and B for which $\bigcup A = \bigcup B$ but $A \ne B$.

This one makes little sense to me. I would think that if the union of two families were the same then so would the over lying set unless I am misunderstanding the problem.

Show that if $A \subseteq B$, then  $\bigcup A \subseteq \bigcup B$

This seems to be along the same lines as the first one.

Show that for any set A, $\bigcup \mathfrak{P}A = A$ and show that $A \subseteq \mathfrak{P}\bigcup A$. Under What conditions does equality hold? The first part just seems definitionally true, based on the definiton of power set.

Show that for any sets A and B, $\mathfrak{P}A \cap\mathfrak{P}B = \mathfrak{P}(A\cap B)$

Show that $\mathfrak{P}A \cup\mathfrak{P}B \subseteq \mathfrak{P}(A\cup B)$.Under what conditions does equality hold?

I am not really sure where to start for these last two

Comment: Aren't the unions over the families $\bigl\{ \{1\},\{2\}\bigr\}$ and $\bigl\{\{1,2\}\bigr\}$ the same?

Comment: To get you started, think about the sets $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$ with respect to your first question. I think once you understand why this works it will give you hints on the others.

Comment: @David: No, because $0\in\bigcup\{1,2\}$ but not in the other one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. I forgot some braces (added now)...

Comment: @Bob : Please follow the general conventions in Mathematics for denoting singleton elements in small letters, sets in capital letters and Family of sets in script letters. (Also use subscripts for the domain of the union.) 

It will improve the general readability of your posts. I have edited for you this time. Just check if you meant the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your intuition about what union is is a bit off. If you think as sets as directed trees where the root is the set itself and where edges mean "belongs to", you can find an example for your first question: in this tree, taking the union of a set $A$ is simply putting everything which is at distance $2$ from the root to distance $1$:

Consider $A = \{\{0,1\}, \{2\} \}$ and $B=\{\{0\}, \{1,2\}\}$. Nodes at distance $1$ aren't the same, so that $A$ and $B$ are different (the former has $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2\}$ at distance 1, the latter $\{0\}$ and $\{1,2\}$). But at distance $2$ from the root, both have the same elements, namely $0,1,2$ so that $\bigcup A = \bigcup B$. See this picture:

[image: picture of $A$ and $B$]

Maybe you can use this picture to visualize how $\mathfrak P A$ and $\bigcup A$ relate in term of trees.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ pe a proper subset of $X$. Then $\{X,Y\}\neq \{X\}$ but $\cup\{X,Y\}=\cup\{X\}$.

$A=\wp\left(\cup A\right)$ if and only if $A=\wp\left(B\right)$
for some $B$.

$X\in\wp\left(A\right)\cap\wp\left(B\right)\iff X\subset A\wedge X\subset B\iff X\subset A\cap B\iff X\in\wp\left(A\cap B\right)$

$X\in\wp\left(A\right)\cup\wp\left(B\right)\iff X\subset A\vee X\subset B\Rightarrow X\subset A\cup B$ i.e. $X\in\wp\left(A\cup B\right)$

$\wp\left(A\right)\cup\wp\left(B\right)=\wp\left(A\cup B\right)$
is true if $X\subset A\cup B$ leads to $X\subset A\vee X\subset B$
wich is true iff $A\subset B\vee B\subset A$

Comment: needs editing !

Comment: @DiffeoR Thanks in advance, but what's wrong then?

Comment: Please see the comment to the original post. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the last two, try taking a member of one group and show that it's on the second one,
for example:
let $C\in P(A∩B)$ then $C \subset A∩B$ , i.e $C \subset A$ and $C \subset B$ which exactly means $C\in P(A)$ and $C\in P(B)$ , and therefore, in their intersection. That shows one inclusion, and the equality can be proven by showing the second direction inclusion.

Same, for the first questions.